# FrameLayout pushing NavigationDrawer action bar up and out

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to achieve a very standard material design layout for my android app. I have a navigation drawer, tabs and floating action button. Each of my fragments should therefore appear in the center of the layout, without overlapping or pushing anything out of the way. When I include my `FrameLayout` with it's default fragment open, it pushes the `ActionBar` (or title bar, whatever) higher and off the screen. My actual java mainly runs fragment transactions and doesn't mess with the layout.

If I exclude the FrameLayout `fragment_container` then the layout acts as normal.

Here is a screenshot. There is meant to be text reading "Material App" above the tab layout.

[image]

This is my XML:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="true">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**tab_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="biz.kusasa.eventually.MainFragment">
</FrameLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.material.demo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="#80d8ff"
        fab:menu_fab_label="">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#43a047"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#388e3c"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#69f0ae"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="@string/openCreate" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#43a047"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#388e3c"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#69f0ae"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Menu item 2" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#8e24aa"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#7b1fa2"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#ea80fc"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="@string/join_group_label" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: If you can then try the tabbed activity provided in android studio templates and implement your code using it

Comment: I had this problem even before I started using the tabs. It seems to be something to do with the framelayout

Comment: try removing linear layout from frame layout

Answer (score 0):

Change Your activity_main.xml like this( keep app_bar_main inside) : LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: This didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: The result of this is a hidden tab layout and I can't swipe between fragments.

Comment: @barnacle.m What does your app_bar_main.xml look like?